# How to delay a function without stopping the application

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

```
void sendCommand(float t,char* cmd)
{

  std::clock_t endwait; 
  double endwait = clock () + t * CLOCKS_PER_SEC ; 
  while (clock() < endwait) {} 
  if( clock() < endwait)
  printf("\nThe waited command is =%s",cmd);

}

void Main()
{
 sendCommand(3.0,"Command1");
 sendCommand(2.0,"Command2");
 printf("\nThe first value")
 return 0;
}
```

i want to delay a function but my application should keep on running.

In the above code i want The first value to be printed first.
than i want Command2 to be printed and Command1 should be the last to be printed.

Comment: You will need to use threads.

Comment: Have a look at `boost::asio`, it's remarkably flexible, and not just for IO.  Threads may (or _may not_) be overkill for your real use case.

Comment: What do you mean by "delay function"? Do you want concurrency, i.e. the `sendCommand`s are executed while the application stops, or do you want to just defer the function calls behind the printf?

Comment: @sumitkang Is the order in which the commands are processed important? If so, you need a queue to serialize the work.

Comment: Commands can be processed in any order but the time delay should be as specified in the function.

Answer (score 9):

I prefer `std::async` for this.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

void sendCommand(std::chrono::seconds delay, std::string cmd)
{
     std::this_thread::sleep_for( delay );
     std::cout << "\nThe waited command is =" << cmd;
}

int main()
{
 auto s1 = std::async(std::launch::async, sendCommand, std::chrono::seconds(3),"Command1");
 auto s2 = std::async(std::launch::async, sendCommand, std::chrono::seconds(2),"Command2");

 std::cout << "\nThe first value" << std::flush;    
 s1.wait();
 s2.wait();


 return 0;
}
```

However, for a real design, I would create a  scheduler (or preferably use an existing one) which manages a priority queue sorted by the delay time. Spawning a new thread for every command will quickly become a problem. Since you flagged the question for MS VIsual C++, take a look [the PPL which implements task-based parallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492427.aspx).

And as it a C++ question, I would stay away from the C stuff and not use `printf`, `CLOCK_PER_SEC`, `char*`, `clock` etc. You will quickly get into problems even with this simple example when you start using strings instead of the "Command1" literals. `std::string` will help you here.

Comment: I am getting a error when i try this code that  async is not a member of std

Comment: @sumitkang I've added the missing headers

Comment: @sumitkang The standard headers in C++ are of the form `<future>` without the suffix. For the C functionality, the headers look like `cstdio`.

Comment: Error 2 error C2664: 'void (std::chrono::milliseconds,char *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'std::chrono::milliseconds' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional 1152 1 ConsoleApplication1

Comment: @sumitkang I've changed the code to use `std::string`. This also solves the lifetime problem of the string parameter because it copies the string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89999/discussion-between-sumit-kang-and-jens).

Comment: I suppose you have to `wait` after printing the "first value", according to OP.

Comment: @Mikhail yes, and it's better  to flush the stream

Answer (score 3):

I think you need threads. You can do it like this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

void sendCommand(float t, char const* cmd)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(int(t * 1000)));
    std::cout << "\nThe waited command is = " << cmd << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    // each function call on a new thread
    std::thread t1(sendCommand, 3.0, "Command1");
    std::thread t2(sendCommand, 2.0, "Command2");

    // join the threads so we don't exit before they finish.
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: i tried using thread as my header file but compiler is not able to open the file.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2012 express version.

Comment: why not use std::chrono::seconds?

Comment: @sumitkang I'm not familiar with VS2012, does it support `C++11`? It needs to support that for this answer to work, also it needs to be turned on (not sure how you do that in VS).

Comment: @Jens The caller passes in a *float* number of seconds. If I used `std::chrono::seconds` then the *fractional part* would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways depending upon your actual logic.
Examles;:

1.you can you a global flag variable and check its state , when third print will complete you can set flag to 1,so next call will execute.

2.you can use a STACK .push all the function pointers in a STACK . and after that pop and execute.

3.MultiThreading. You can use it with proper synchronized way, but it will be complex. It depends upon your requirement.

Thanks !!!

Comment: I will not be able to use global variable as i can have multiple send command functions.

Comment: In that case use STACK.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::asio` is nice because it doesn't require the overhead of multiple threads.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service svc;

    boost::asio::deadline_timer t0{svc};
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t1{svc};
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t2{svc};

    t0.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds{1});
    t1.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds{2});
    t2.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds{3});

    t2.async_wait([] (const boost::system::error_code& ec) { if(!ec) std::cout << "Greetings from t2!\n";});
    t1.async_wait([] (const boost::system::error_code& ec) { if(!ec) std::cout << "Greetings from t1!\n";});
    t0.async_wait([] (const boost::system::error_code& ec) { if(!ec) std::cout << "Greetings from t0!\n";});

    svc.post([] () { std::cout << "I'm number one!\n";});

    svc.run();

    return 0;
}
```

Gives the output:

```
I'm number one!
Greetings from t0!
Greetings from t1!
Greetings from t2!
```